# Every time I add a new file in Visual Studio, I have to manaully add it to Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have .NET Core 7 sln with 10 projects and I am using Visual Studio 2022, version 17.4.4. The problem is that every time I add a new file to project it is not tracked be git and I have to manaully add it to Source Control. This happens for 9 out of 10 projects.

The source control is git repository.

[Ignored file in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNQF6.png)

I have checked .gitignore and I compared projects settings across whole sln.
Is there any hidden setting in Visual Studio or solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Might be worth checking if there is more than one `.gitignore` file involved.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the "Automatically detect when files are changed outside of Visual Studio" option is turned off in Visual Studio. To turn it on, go to "Tools" > "Options" > "Environment" > "Documents" and check the "Detect when file is changed outside the environment" option.

If that doesn't work, you can try adding the new file to git using the command line, to see if the issue is with Visual Studio or with git itself.

Also, check the .gitignore file to make sure that the newly added file is not being ignored by git.

Finally, make sure that the projects are properly configured for git source control by going to "File" > "Source Control" > "Advanced" > "Change Source Control" and ensuring that all projects are properly bound to git.

Comment: None of this is helpful.